# Python integer programming: looking for constraint on set partitioning

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have a set partitioning problem that requires each available period to be used only once.

```
def solve (slots, reqs, periods):
    # binary variable to id if combination is used
    x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('slot', slots, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

    # linear program problem
    sked_model = pulp.LpProblem("NLE Specials Scheduling Model", pulp.LpMaximize)

    # objective function
    sked_model += sum([x[slot] for slot in slots]), "Slot selection" # all combinations considered equal

    # Supply maximum number of slots
    sked_model += sum([x[slot] for slot in slots]) == len(reqs), "Number_of_slots to sked"
```

## ERROR OCCURS HERE

```
    # A period can only be used once
    for period in periods:
        sked_model += sum([x[slot] for slot in slots if period == slot[0:2]]) <= 1, "Period_used_no_more_than_once" 

    # The problem is solved using PuLP’s choice of Solver
    sked_model.solve()
```

The error received is "pulp.constants.PulpError: overlapping constraint names:" on the # period can only be used once constraint.

Comment: The problem is that you give the same name to different constraints. Try `"Period_used_no_more_than_once_{}".format(period)` instead of `"Period_used_no_more_than_once"`. Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510382/i-there-a-way-to-specify-two-constraints-for-the-same-variable-when-using-puthon)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this.

The error came from the constraint name, "Period_used_no_more_than_once", being used more than once when the constraints were built. By replacing that name with "", the constraint worked as desired.

New constraint:

> for period in periods:
>           sked_model += sum([x[slot] for slot in slots if period == slot[0:2]]) <= 1, ""